# MobX passing simple array from observable to observer

Tags: arrays, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am new to MobX and was recommended it here.
I have a simple array which I am trying to pass to another file.
I have tried many things but I am unable to receive the array in the form of this.props.store
If you could shine some light on my improper use of mobX it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/styles.js';
import {observable, extendObservable} from 'mobx';

//unsure why below code wont work, when trying to export it throws error: object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new rNumStore()')
// const rNumStore = observable([1,2,3]);

// a couple of other options both i am unsure why they do not work
// class rNumStore {
//  extendObservable(this, {
//   rNumbers: [1,2,3]});
// }
// class rNumStore {
// observable({rNumbers: [1,2,3]});
// }

//Current best working solution below
var rNumStore = function(){
    extendObservable(this, {
         rNumbers: [1,2,3]
    });
}


var Button = React.createClass({
    rNumberGen: function(){

        store.rNumbers = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];

        var a = store.rNumbers[0].toString();
        var d =store.rNumbers.toString();
        Alert.alert(a, d);
        //this alert gives mobxArray of random numbers
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.rNumberGen} style=    {styles.center}>
                        <Text style={styles.button}>Generate!</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
    }

});

var store = new rNumStore;
export default store;

export {Button};
```

Then the second file needs to observe the array

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import{
    genre1,
    genre2,
    genre3
} from './genres.js';

import styles from '../styles/styles.js';

import {observer} from 'mobx-react/native';


var Genre = observer(React.createClass({

    alert: function(){
        //below does not cause an error.
        var a = this.props.store;
        //undefined ins not an object(evaluating 'this.props.store.rNumbers')
        // have tried making 'a' a state : this.props.store.rNumbers same error occurs at that point
        var b = this.props.store.rNumbers[1];
        var c = b.toString();
        Alert.alert('this is', c);

    },
    render: function(){
        let genre = this.props.selected;
        return(
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.alert}>
                <View style={styles.genre}>
                    <Text style={styles.center}>{genre}</Text>
                </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            );
    },
}));



module.exports = Genre;
```

Comment: where is you main app code? that should create the store, then in it's render it should have <Genre store={store}> and <Button store={store}> tags that you pass the store to as a property

Comment: Honestly Peter, you are my guardian. After a while tinkering this got me to my solution. Would you like to post it as an answer and I can mark it correct. Or I can post a full solution in case anyone has a similar problem

Comment: Posted as an answer. If you have edit rights you can add code if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your main app code? That should create the store, then in it's render it should have  and  tags that you pass the store to as a property

Edit:
The main store needs a class:

```
class rNumStore {
  rNumbers = observable([1,2,3])

  rNumGen() {
    this.rNumbers = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]
    //Alert.alert('this is', rNumbers.toString())
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Genre Genrerator</Text>

            <Text style={[styles.h2, styles.h21]}>I am listening to</Text>
            <View style={styles.genreContainer}>
                 <Genre store={store} selected='{genre[1]}'/>
                 <Genre store={store} selected='{genre[2]}'/>
                 <Genre store={store} selected='{genre[3]}'/>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.h2}>You filthy casual</Text>
            <Button store={store}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


var store = new rNumStore;
export default store;
module.exports = Main;
```

which is exported as above.
Then as Peter says the store then needs to be passed into the props of the observer classes.
Thanks for the help.